# Pushforward by étale morphisms of locally constant sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology, pushforward

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally constant étale sheaf of modules on a scheme $X$. If $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ is étale and surjective, can I say that $\phi_*\mathcal{F}$ is locally constant?

My idea is that if $\{U_i\rightarrow X\}$ is an étale cover of $X$ such that $\mathcal{F}|_{U_i}$ is constant, then $\{U_i\rightarrow X\rightarrow Y\}$ should be a  cover of $Y$ such that $\phi_*\mathcal{F}|_{U_i}$ is constant.

How far is this from being true? What condition could I put on $\phi$ to assure that $\phi_*\mathcal{F}$ is locally constant?

Comment: Well, at least $\phi$ should be surjective. Otherwise $\{U_i \to X \to Y\}$ wouldn't be an étale cover of $Y$.

Comment: Yep I've edited the question. Thx

Comment: surjective is not enough, we need proper. Then $\phi_*\Lambda$ is not locally constant. On the other hand, if $\phi$ is proper and étale (actually, if $\phi$ is proper and smooth) then $\phi_*\mathcal{F}$ is locally constant (actually, even the higher direct images).